# Tabla (HTML) solo muestra el último registro del array (JS)

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Tengo la siguiente parte de código en JS para mostrar en una tabla, pero en vez de mostrarme todos los registros del array, solo me muestra el último:

```
for (var i = 0; i < datos.lpaElementPrivativo.length; i++) {
   console.info(datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i]);
   let tdo = document.querySelector('#tdo');
   tdo.innerHTML = `
        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].descriptionElementPrivativo}</td>
        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].unit}</td>
        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].quantity}</td>
        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].vrnPerUnit}</td>
        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].remainingLife}</td>
        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].age}</td>
        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].ageFactor}</td>
        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].conservationfactor}</td>
        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].resultfactorfre}</td>
        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${Math.round(datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].netrv*100)/100}</td>
        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].partialvalue}</td>`
```

Y así está mi tabla en HTML5:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
   <table style=" width: 1141px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
       <thead style="color: white;background-color: #53A5E1; height: 50px !important; width: 1221px !important; font-size: 11px;">
            <tr>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; width: 150px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">DESCRIPCION</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; width: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">UNIDAD</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; width: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">CANT.</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; width: 50px !important; padding: 0px !important; text-align: center; font-size: 11px;">V.R. NUEVO</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 50px !important;">V. R. REMANENTE</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 120px !important;">EDAD EN AÑOS</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 120px !important;">FACTOR EDAD</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 50px !important;">FACTOR CONSERVACIÓN</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; width: 150px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 50px !important;">FACTOR RESULTANTE</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 50px !important;">V.R. NETO ($/M2)</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; width: 150px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 150px !important;">VALOR PARCIAL ÁREAS COMUNES</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr id="tdo">
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Pido su ayuda para poder mostrar todos mis registros y de antemano les agradezco todo su apoyo.

Comment: Estás seteando en cada ciclo la variable tdo.innerHTML. Si intentas agregando todo el html a una variable con += y al finalizar el if le asignas esa variable al tdo.innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un id a la tabla y luego prueba esto:

```
let tbody = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

for (var i = 0; i < datos.lpaElementPrivativo.length; i++) {
    let nuevaFila = tbody.insertRow();
    nuevaFila.innerHTML = `<td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].descriptionElementPrivativo}</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].unit}</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].quantity}</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].vrnPerUnit}</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].remainingLife}</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].age}</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].ageFactor}</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].conservationfactor}</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].resultfactorfre}</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${Math.round(datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].netrv*100)/100}</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].partialvalue}</td>`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que quieres agregar filas de forma dinamica

```html
 <script type="application/javascript">
        function mia() {
            let tdo = document.getElementById('tdo');

            for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                tr.innerHTML = `<tr>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">hola</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">hola</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">hola</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">hola</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">hola</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">hola</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">hola</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">hola</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">hola</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">hola</td>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;"></td> </tr>`
                tdo.children[0].appendChild(tr);
            }

        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="mia()"> ADD</button>

    
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <table style=" width: 1141px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <thead
            style="color: white;background-color: #53A5E1; height: 50px !important; width: 1221px !important; font-size: 11px;">
        <tr>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; width: 150px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">
                DESCRIPCION
            </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; width: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">
                UNIDAD
            </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; width: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">
                CANT.
            </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; width: 50px !important; padding: 0px !important; text-align: center; font-size: 11px;">
                V.R. NUEVO
            </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 50px !important;">
                V. R. REMANENTE
            </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 120px !important;">
                EDAD EN AÑOS
            </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 120px !important;">
                FACTOR EDAD
            </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 50px !important;">
                FACTOR CONSERVACIÓN
            </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; width: 150px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 50px !important;">
                FACTOR RESULTANTE
            </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 50px !important;">
                V.R. NETO ($/M2)
            </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black !important; height: 50px; width: 150px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; width: 150px !important;">
                VALOR PARCIAL ÁREAS COMUNES
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tdo">
        <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

El detalle es que le has puesto un id a tu tr pero no lo estas accediendo correctamente deberia ser ademas imagino que quieres agregarle filas a la tabla:

```
let tdo = document.getElementById('tdo'); // fuera de tu ciclo for
```

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dice @Bicho, el código no funciona porque dentro del bucle no concatenas, sino que cambias el contenido sin más con  `tdo.innerHTML =`.

Pero además de eso, dentro del bucle creas cada vez una referencia al elemento `tdo` del DOM con `let tdo = document.querySelector('#tdo');`

Hacer todo eso dentro de un bucle, aparte de afectar el rendimiento, provoca que no funcione al no concatenar.

La buena práctica exige que:

1. Crees las referencias a los elementos fuera de los bucles
2. Evites modificar los elementos fuera de los bucles, con `innerHTML` o de otro modo, sino que crees una variable para recoger las filas y modifiques el elemento **una sola vez** al salir de bucle.

Por otra parte, si se trata de agregar varias filas al body de la tabla, convendría crearlas como tal dentro del bucle y luego agregarlas a `tbody`. Para hacer eso primeramente puedes darle un `id` a la tabla, por ejemplo:

```
        <table id="mTable" style="width: 1141px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
```

Y luego, en Javascript:

Por ejemplo:

```
/*Variable para concatenar*/
var mHTML="";
/*Referencia al tbody*/
let tBody = document.querySelector('#mTable tbody');

for (var i = 0; i < datos.lpaElementPrivativo.length; i++) {
                    console.info(datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i]);
                    /*OJO agregamos la etiqueta <tr>*/
                    mHTML+=`
                       <tr>
                        <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lpaElementPrivativo[i].descriptionElementPrivativo}</td>
                       </tr>`
                        /*Aquí todos los otros td y no olvides cerrar </tr>*/
}
/*Ahora sí modificamos el elemento*/
tBody.innerHTML=mHTML;
```

Como recomendación final. Evita los estilos *in line*  y el uso de `!important`. Considera mejor usar clases CSS.